# User in an EC2 instance that’s assigned a S3 full access role can’t access S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-cli, cloud-security

The EC2 instance has an IAM role assigned to it allowing it the full access to S3. I think this would allow any user in that instance to access S3, like issuing command `aws s3 ls`. But it turns out that only the default ec2-user and root(using sudo) are allowed. What should I do to grant any user in the instance to access S3 without having to use sudo?

Comment: It sounds like the other users might have some locally-stored credentials that are overriding the credentials provided by the Instance Metadata Service. If you look at [Credentials — Boto3 Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html), you'll see that other methods are tried before Instance Metadata. Check whether the other users have Environment Variables or a `~/.aws/credentials` file. You could also try `aws iam get-user`, which might give a hint as to which credentials are being used.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes indeed! It’s the credentials in ~/.aws/credentials that interferes. Is there anyway to configure instance meta data service to ignore ~/.aws/credentials, because I need the credentials there? Thank you

Comment: No. The AWS SDK has a "Credentials Chain" where it looks. The AWS CLI uses Python, so it follows the boto3 credentials chain that I linked above. As soon as it finds one, it stops. Why do you have credentials in a file, if you wish to use the IAM Role?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it's a bit complicated. The role is used to allow users on the instances to access S3 buckets, and in additon to that, we need to access other resources, which needes additional credentials... anyway, it's solved now. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue and resolved by doing below steps.
First i have checked the ~/.aws/credentials file on both user.
/home/ec2-user/.aws/credentials
/root/.aws/credentials

now i have commented the aws key and secret key in **/root/.aws/credentials**

like  this.

```
[default]
#aws_access_key_id = youraws key
#aws_secret_access_key = your secrete key
```

this is all because root user is using the different access keys to access the aws resources.